# Is there any function available in nodejs to generate the statement on the basis of month, day, year, or in between selected dates in .xls format?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, npm

I'm writing a code for backend in nodejs and want to generate a statement on monthly basis, daily basis, yearly basis, or between some particular date in .xls format.

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: Did you find anything useful?